# why SR LSP no tunnel interface? but SR TE need it?

Tags: cisco, mpls, mpls-vpn, mpls-te

I'm a bit confused that why SR LSP(or LDP LSP) no need to config a tunnel interface, but SR TE(or MPLS TE) need it.

how the tunnel interface works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SR-LSP (or LDP-LSP) tunnels are automatically created based on Node-SIDs (or LDP labels) advertised by other nodes. These are loose tunnels which follow the shortest IGP path to the destination. Hence there is no need for an explicit tunnel interface configuration for them.

On the other hand, SR-TE (or MPLS-TE) tunnels are the traffic engineering tunnels which requires explicit configurations like strict paths, admin-groups, te-metric, hop-count, SRLG etc.. Purpose of these tunnels is to force traffic to a path other than shortest IGP path. Hence manual tunnel interface configuration is required.

MPLS services will use the tunnels allowed in the tunnel binding configurations. If a service is configured with SR-LSP tunnel resolution, it will use the SR-LSP tunnel only. If tunnel resolution is SR-TE, it will use SR-TE tunnels only. If resolution is allowed to "any" then it will choose based on tunnel table preference values. By default SR-TE tunnels are preferred over SR-LSP tunnels.